# Simple script not working in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, formatting, phone-number

I'm just trying to format a phone number while I'm typing it.

The phone is in a table, it looks like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="200">Phone number : </td>
            <td width="200"><form:input fieldId="phone" fieldType="text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And I have this script and the top of the page, where there's other scripts... that works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#phone").mask("999-999-999");
</script>
```

I can't find why it won't work...

Thanks for futur help

EDIT: Also tried this:

```
$('#phone').keyup(function() {
    var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}$|.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
    $(this).val(foo);
});
```

EDIT 2: It works fine when I'm using a normal input... but it seems that it won't work using form:input

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I need to "include" jquery before my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=CONTEXTPATH%>/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=CONTEXTPATH%>/scripts/myScript.js"></script>
```